# Applying np.where in a sliding window

Tags: python, numpy, sliding-window

I have an array of `True`/`False` values which I want to use as a repeating mask over another array of a different shape.

```py
import numpy as np

mask = np.array([[ True, True],
                 [False, True]])

array = np.random.randint(10, size=(64, 64))
```

I want to apply this mask in a sliding window, similar to the `where` function on the array. Currently, I use `np.kron` to simply repeat the mask to match the dimensions of the array:

```py
layout = np.ones((array.shape[0]//mask.shape[0], array.shape[1]//mask.shape[1]), dtype=bool)
mask = np.kron(layout, mask)
result = np.where(mask, array, 255) # example usage
```

Is there any elegant way to do this same operation, without repeating the `mask` into the same shape as `array`? I was hoping there would be some kind of sliding window technique or convolution/correlation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use broadcasting with reshape so you wouldn't need extra memory for the repeated `mask`:

```
x, y = array.shape[0]// mask.shape[0], array.shape[1] // mask.shape[1]

result1 = np.where(mask[None, :, None], 
                  array.reshape(x, mask.shape[0], y, mask.shape[1]), 
                  255).reshape(array.shape)
```

Comment: Woah, I have no idea how this works, but it seems to do what I was looking for. Guess I need to learn a lot more about shapes. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `np.tile`:

```
np.where(np.tile(mask, (a//m for a,m in zip(array.shape, mask.shape))), array, 255)
```

Comment: This seems to do the same as my solution with np.kron but a bit more efficiently, not exactly what I was looking for but still good to know.